# How to split a String in an array to individual char?

Tags: arrays, string, input, character

I have this simple code that split an input and put it in array of String:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    String[] arraySentence = s.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i<arraySentence.length; i++) {
        arraySentence[i].toCharArray();

        System.out.println(arraySentence[i].toCharArray());
    }
```

my focus is to manage every character of every single word into the array.

For example if I pass: "*now we only have*"

the string from input becomes: `arraySentence{now, we, only, have}` and I want to be able to take the "n" after the "o" then "w", etc.

How can do it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to achieve what you want to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<char[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

     String s = "now we only have";
     String[] arraySentence = s.split(" ");

     for(String str : arraySentence) {
         list.add(str.toCharArray());
     }

     list.forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
}
```

`list` contains `char` arrays. Do whatever you want to do with them...

**Output**

```
[n, o, w]
[w, e]
[o, n, l, y]
[h, a, v, e]
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly, if not please leave a comment to be able to modify and correct. Inside your loop you can use the one of following snippet based on your needs.

```
char[] arr = arraySentence[i].toCharArray();
//in case you need n - o  - w
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
 System.out.print(arr[i]);
}

//also you can do this too 
for(char c: arr){
 System.out.print(arr[i]);
}
//in case you need w - o - n
for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
 System.out.print(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: your loop is infinite, let me check better

Comment: which one exactly, :)  the first or the second.. can you check updated answer

Comment: correct, thanks I was able to do that, but i forgot to put this instrution : System.out.print(arr[blu]+ " \n   "); so I never see the correct result.

Comment: Great, would you please mark it as a valid and correct answer if it helped you